# php header("location: test.php") not working. But java script redirect working

Tags: php, javascript

```
php header("location: test.php")
```

not working. But java script redirect working .

I tried with `header()` doesn't redirects?

```
header("location: test.php");
```

but i tried with java script its working

```
window.location ="http://www.test.com/test.php"
```

what is the problem. please give some solution

before calling header there no echo ( output commands )

there is no error / warning messages

My exact code :

```
if($contlogin >0 && $LoginID!="")
{      
    $_SESSION['LoginID'] = $LoginID;
    if($_SESSION['currentUrl']) {
        header("location: http://".$_SESSION['currentUrl']);
    }
    else {
        if($LoginID==1) {
            header("location:admin/index.php");
        }
        else {
            header("location:dashboard.php");
        }
    }
}
else {   
    header("location:index.php?err=1");
}
```

Comment: Can you paste all of your PHP code?

Comment: Open up the site in Chrome and press F12 and look at your headers for the page - did it even include the Location tag?

Answer (score 3):

Place a `exit()` after      `header("location: test.php");`

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is space before your php tag `<?php`

Check your error_reporting is on or off, if it is off make it on

Comment: there no space after or before <?php ?>

Comment: check in all the php pages included in your page, before the header statement.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you probably have an error in your PHP, likely a syntax error. From the command line you can run PHP's lint checker to look for errors:

```
php -l scriptname.php
```

Alternatively, enabling [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) either in php.ini or at runtime in your script might help you figure out what's going on.

If you haven't checked it yet, your webserver's error log may also provide a clue as to what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cant comment until I get my rep up so I gotta post this
But your php opening tag might have just a space before it, and that causes the header not to work... so `<?php` might have a space or something before it...

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the **l** in `location:` should be **L** .

```
header("Location:test.php");
```

Also use exit() after header() to avoid any problems and stop execution of script as suggested by another poster.

Comment: both i tried
header("Location:test.php"); and 
header("location:test.php");

Comment: Could you also check if any of your if-else case is even triggered by commenting header() and echoing for all the three cases

Answer (score 0):

some reasons for not working header();
1. if there is space before the php tag it wont work
2. echo statement before header()
 if u found this Add exit() or die() after the header()

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code must be sending some information to the page before header kicks in. In my case I had some JavaScript code in the body section. Which causes some data (although not immediately visible) causing the location not to work.

Please check your logs for some entry such as:

```js
[Mon Apr 13 13:53:29 2015] [error] [client 192.168.109.109] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/xxx.php:208) in /var/www/html/xxx.php on line 565, referer: https://www.acme.com/xxx.php
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add the ob_start(); function in the top of the php page, then redirect  function will work fine.**

***link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php***